# Is context switch time included in thread quantum time?

Tags: .net, multithreading, context-switch

I mean if quantum time of thread is 20 ms, so some time (15 ms) of 20 is spent in context switch and other (5 ms) on execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would dump any OS that spends 75% of its time context-switching on an average basis.  I would only expect such a load on a transitive basis when a lot of prioritised threads get made ready in an unfortunate, rapid sequence by I/O interrupts/signals and so cause 'sequential' changes in the set of ready threads.

It would be better is developers/posters stopped using terms like 'quantum' and 'time-slice' so often when referring to preemptive kernels.  Except on grossly-overloaded boxes, the tick interrupt is only useful for timing out other blocking calls and sleeping for intervals.

Who came up with 'quantum' as a  term for this anyway?  A 'quantum' is indivisible, whereas 99.9% of all, household threads are waiting on I/O or each other for most of the time, run for less than the tick period, are immediately allocated a core and made running when they become ready and hardly ever experience being peempted just because of their 'time-slice' is up.

'time-slice' sounds like something from the 60's, not in 2012 with preemptive kernels responding rapidly to driver interrupts/signals and immediately making those thread/s that were waiting ready/running.

Comment: I didn't said 75%. The numbers are just for example. I want to know if context switch time is part of the execution time given to thread? And how long it takes for context switch in .Net?

Answer (score 0):

It is an implementation detail.

What happens on Linux is that when the process/thread scheduler assigns a CPU to a thread, that thread is considered running. The code it executes switching from the kernel mode back to the user mode is considered kernel code executed on behalf of that process/thread and hence the context switch time is accounted as the thread/process run-time.

Comment: do yon how much time is spent for context switch using .NET ThreadPool for example?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as 'Context Switch in .NET', since .NET is not an operating system and 
all those thread-related CLR libraries are just wrappers around OS's API.

So the question should be something like: "how long it takes for context switch on Windows?"

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on implementations details.

The tenth edition of "Operating System Concepts" (Silberschartz, Gagne, Galvin) says when explaining Round Robin Scheduling (page 210):

> "The CPU scheduler picks the first process from the ready queue, sets a timer to interrupt after 1 time quantum, and dispatches the process."

Where the dispatch process, defined on page 203, includes:

- context switch
- switch to user mode
- jumping to the PC

There are also statements that indicates the context switch is included in the quantum or time slice. For example, in RR again, it says:

> "Each process must wait no longer than (n-1) x q time units until its next quantum."